# Combine aggregations from two nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

How can I create an combined aggregation in Elasticsearch using multiple nested objects?

What I want to achieve is the SUM of quantity grouped by country in a mapping that looks like this

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200' -d '{
    "index": "test",
    "type": "orders",
    "body": {
        "orders": {
            "order_number": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "buyer": {
                "properties": {
                    "country": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            },
            "products": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "quantity": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Using this test data

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk' -d '
    {"index": {"_index": "test", "_type": "orders", "_id": 1}}
    {"order_number": "1", "buyer": {"country": "US"}, "products": [{"name": "A product", "quantity": 10}]}
    {"index": {"_index": "test", "_type": "orders", "_id": 2}}
    {"order_number": "2", "buyer": {"country": "DE"}, "products": [{"name": "A product", "quantity": 10}]}
    {"index": {"_index": "test", "_type": "orders", "_id": 3}}
    {"order_number": "3", "buyer": {"country": "US"}, "products": [{"name": "A product", "quantity": 10}]}
'
```

The result should be that there was sold 10 "A product" in DE and 20 in US. How can I create this aggregation when the properties in question are on separate nested objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have aggregations inside other aggregations.

Something like this should work - you might need to specify nested path:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "buyer_country": { 
      "terms": {
        "field": "buyer.country"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "quantity_of_product" : { "sum" : { "field" : "products.quantity" } }
    }
  }
}
```

see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html

and: https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations

Comment: This does not work since you are not using a nested aggregation. You need to use nested aggregation when doing aggregation using nested properties. My issue is that I am aggregating using two separate nested objects. If I create a nested aggregation on country and inside this create a reverse nested aggregation and then sum the quantity in a second aggregation I will loose the context of the first aggregation when doing the reverse aggregation.

Comment: On a side node I think your second `aggs` also need to be inside `buyer_country`

Comment: Ah, your solution will work if I do not map buyer as a `nested` type but map it is an `object` instead. That makes sense to do so instead - thank you!

Comment: @Esben can you update this question with the mapping and query that solved your problem. Might help future visitors :)